# Web Speech API in hand-rolled in-app browser

Tags: cordova, capacitor

My company serves e-learning lessons through HTML5 files created in H5P, Captivate, Storyline. These lessons use xAPI to communicate grades and user information to an LRS. Recently I have been working on implementing voice recognition into these lessons using either [Web speech API](https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/) or [Annyang](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang) and eventually we would like to build our own proprietary speech API. However, I see that voice recognition only seems to be [compatible](https://caniuse.com/speech-recognition) with Chrome desktop right now. I am working on creating a mobile app using React Native that can access a user's lessons from the database and "play" them in an in-app browser. So my questions are as follows:

1. Would it be possible to hand-roll an in-app browser like Capacitor/ Cordova/ some other IAB to support the [W3C Web Speech API specification](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/)?
2. Would it even be allowed? Would Apple allow an app with such an IAB in their app store?
3. Am I correct in understanding that an in-app browser could still support the necessary Javascript for features like xAPI, drag and drop, and session progress saving? Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Which Speech API's? The spec you referenced is broad and includes a number of underlying API's which are [supported across different platforms](https://caniuse.com/?search=speech).
2. Probably not. Many apps submitted this way get rejected. [Apple is against](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#hardware-compatibility) the method you're trying to load the app. An app that simply loads an IAB is not really an app to Apple.

> 2.5.2: Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area...

3. IAB is a hit or miss. They can't access native features through plugins. It should support most web standards, but from my experience, they're use for [simpler use cases](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/). Not hosting feature rich apps. Why not make a regular Cordova/Capacitor app without the IAB?

Comment: I want to preserve my user sessions across multiple app launches, have the flexibility to download lessons to be "played" offline, build a native .APK/ .IPA, be able to access the device microphone, and provide a highly responsive app. Would Cordova/Capacitor be suited for this? I also heard that Apple may start banning web-based apps from their app store--is this true?

Comment: Yes, Cordova/Capacitor can allow for all of that you mentioned. No. Not true. As of right now Apple will not ban web-based app. Cordova/Capacitor apps get submitted often. They do ban apps that violate the rule I quoted above. If you're trying to submit an app that only launches an IAB, you will likely not get past approval.